# Create asp.net batches of emails from datareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have 153 email addresses returned from a stored procedure (this number could vary) which I load into a `SqlDataReader` (`r`). My email relay server can send up to 50 email addresses at a time.  How can I create X number of groups so I don't exceed its limit, from the reader?

```vb
Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand("sproc_Get_Emails", myConnection)
myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

myCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@List_Type", SqlDbType.Char))
myCommand.Parameters("@List_Type").Value = priority

Dim r As SqlDataReader
myConnection.Open()
r = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

I am at a blank on how to do this.  My thinking was along this...

```vb
'get count of all email addresses and divide by 50, then send each in 50 record batches???
 Dim email_count As Integer = 0

 'get count and divide by 50 
  email_count = r.RecordsAffected

  Dim list_size As Double = email_count / 50
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11463734/952310

Comment: Why did you tag C# when your sample code is in VB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic way is to use a counter variable:

```vb
Dim count as Integer
Dim address as String

While r.Read
    address = address + r.Field("email") + ";"
    count = count + 1
    If count = 50 Then
        ' send 
        count = 0
        address = ""
    End If
End While
' see if there are any remaining addresses 
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(address) Then
    ' send
End If
```

Other ways:

- Use a [Linq extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11463734/952310) to batch the emails into groups of 50, then loop through them
- Use Ling `Skip` and `Take` in a loop to do effectively the same thing