# Split collection into groups of different sizes

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection "cases" (`IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>`), which I would like to split into chunks like the following, where each second row contains two columns:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">2</div>
   <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">5</div>
   <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
```

I have seen different approaches using extension methods, e.g. `.Chunk(2)`, `.Batch(2)` or `.Split(2)`, but mostly where it is splitted into fixed sizes e.g. [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7]

For now I have the following:

```
var batches = w
            .Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
            .GroupBy(p => (p.i / (p.i % 2 == 0 ? 2 : 1)), p => p.x);

var rows = batches;
var count = 0;
foreach (var row in rows)
{
   <div class="row">
       @foreach (var c in row)
       {
           <div class="col">@(count+1)</div>
           count++;
       }
    </div>
}
```

When the collection contains 7 elements, the output is:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">2</div>
   <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">4</div>
   <div class="col">5</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">6</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">7</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestion how I can get the output as in the first example?

Comment: Why are you dividing?  You just really need p.1 % 2.

Comment: No, that tried that too, which splitted the collection into two group - first one with 4 and second one with 3. So the output rendered two rows, which 4 columns in first row and 3 columns in second row.

Comment: Then you want to divide by 2 :  p => (int)(p.i/2)

Comment: It was similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24087164/1693918 but I didn't want equal chunks sizes, but rather 1, 2, 1, 2,.. chunks per group.

Comment: Isn't 1,2; 1,2; 1,2; two groups?  1,2 are the two items in each row.  So if you enumerate through the groups you get your results.

Comment: @jdweng it was also what I did first, but that returns chunks of 2 items per group .. and with 7 elements, then 1 item in last group.

Comment: Yes, but `.GroupBy(p => p.i / 2, p => p.x);` returns [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7]
I need: [1], [2,3], [4], [5, 6], [7], etc.

Comment: You should only get four groups, not seven.  You are doing something wrong if you are getting 7 groups.  0/2 and 1/2 = 0; 2/2 and 3/2 = 1; 4/2 and 5/2 = 2; 6/2 = 3.  So your groups are 0,1,2,3.  You may be getting confused because your columns are starting a 1 while the indexing starts at zero.

Comment: The brackets marks the group. So having 7 elements in the collection:
When using `.GroupBy(p => p.i / 2, p => p.x)` it returns two groups with 4 items in first and 3 items in second.

When using `.GroupBy(p => p.i / 2, p => p.x)` it returns four groups with 2 items in each of the first 3 groups and 1 item in last group: [1,2], [3,4], [5,6], [7]

Comment: It was not an issue to split into chunks of equal sizes, but when it should returns different items in each group. But the answer posted by @Ivan Stoev solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use `GroupBy` with composite key first to split the input to triples and then to split the triple to pair:

```
var batches = w.Select((x, i) => new { x, i })
    .GroupBy(e => new { K1 = e.i / 3, K2 = e.i % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1 })
    .Select(g => g.Select(e => e.x).ToArray())
    .ToList();
```

Another way would be to produce a single grouping key using the same idea:

```
.GroupBy(e => 2 * (e.i / 3) + (e.i % 3 == 0 ? 0 : 1))
```