# List<string> to List<List<string>> with linq or lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am having a list which contains 243 strings. I want to split the list into several smaller lists containing 20 strings each. Obviously, the last list should have 3 strings. I want the format to be List>.

How do accomplish this with linq och lambda?

To the ones who cares: When I have my lists, i will use foreach on them to call an API with only so many string at a time.

Comment: Any input data example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087164/5133585

Comment: NuGet "System.Reactive" and then do `list.Buffer(20)`.

Comment: Thank you Sweeper, that linked did the work. I paste the code that I finally used: var result = source
            .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 20)
            .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
            .ToList();