# Splitting a List into chunks - C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list which consists of around 1,000,000 records. And, I am using EF to insert it into the database. Since it takes too long I need to split this List into blocks of 100 records and save.

How can I do this?

```
await dbCont.People.AddAsync(peoples);
await dbCont.Savechanges();
```

The people's List here contains 1,000,000 records. And instead of saving all at once (slows the insert), I need to insert around 100 records at a time. How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at linq `Skip` and `Take`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/return-or-skip-elements-in-a-sequence

Comment: @TomJohn Are you aware of any method where I could insert bulk using EF ?

Comment: You're aware that this will likely create 10.000 transactions, if one of them fails, the previous transactions have already been committed?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen How do you think I could overcome my issue ?

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463734/split-a-list-into-smaller-lists-of-n-size - it might help.

Comment: Keep the code as-is, or try to follow up on true bulk insert solution. Problem is that entity framework is doing a lot of work behind the scenes and bulk insert might bypass that so it may not be possible to use.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Is there any Nuget packages/framework you are aware that I could use?

Comment: A big performance issue is that during EF generates an INSERT for each object when calling SaveChanges. There is a bulk insert extensibility in the EF Core library, but it's not cheap.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a List into smaller lists of N size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463734/split-a-list-into-smaller-lists-of-n-size)

Comment: MyList.Chunk(100) is also now available in .Net 7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
var batchSize = 100;
var processed = 0;
var hasNextBatch = true;

while(hasNextBatch) 
{
    var batch = peoples.Skip(processed).Take(batch).ToList();
    await dbCont.People.AddAsync(batch);
    await dbCont.Savechanges();
    processed += batch.count;
    hasNextBatch = batch.Count == batchSize;
}
```

but you will have to consider that when a batch insert fails, the previous batches are already committed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the extension method [Batch](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_Batch__1.htm) of the library [MoreLinq](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ): *Batches the source sequence into sized buckets.*

```
var list = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 25));
var buckets = list.Batch(size: 10);
foreach (var bucket in buckets)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bucket));
}
```

Output

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
21, 22, 23, 24, 25
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to insert chunks in EF in past, but it is slow because of entity tracking. 
Of course you can disable entity tracking, but better use [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8) to bulk insert. Here is a good article [Bulk inserting data into SQL Server](http://richorama.github.io/2017/11/28/sql-bulk-copy/).

Comment: Can I use something that goes along with EF ?

Comment: EF is bad for bulk insert, in case you want bulk insert using entities you can use Dapper:  https://dapper-tutorial.net/bulk-insert

Answer (score 0):

Below is to split in 500 chunks, we can use any number to chunk of 100 or 1000, instead of 500. Just replace and get going. Happy Coding!!

C# Code:

````
 public string OrdersListsplitAndProcess(List<OrderInfo> OrigOrdersList)
        {
            int rowscount = 0, totCount = OrigOrdersList.Count;
            int remainder = (totCount % 500); int FinalQuotient = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(Convert.ToDecimal(totCount / 500)));
            int thisQuotient = 0;
            List<OrderInfo> thisOrdersList = new List<OrderInfo>();
            for (int i = 0; i < totCount; i++)
            {
                thisOrdersList.Add(OrigOrdersList[i]);
                rowscount++;
                if (rowscount == 500 || (thisQuotient == FinalQuotient && rowscount == remainder))
                {
                    processOpenOrders(thisOrdersList);// CHUNCKED LIST
                    thisOrdersList.Clear(); // TO RESET and PREPARE FOR NEXT CHUNK
                    if (rowscount != remainder)
                        thisQuotient++;
                    rowscount = 0;
                }
            }
            return "finished successfully";
        } ```
````