# How to create sublists from a list with linq?

Tags: c#, list, linq

Here is another way [Split a List into smaller lists of N size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463734)

The purpose of this post is to share knowledge involving "Linq" and opinions without using "for" ties and "ranges" directly.

Example: I have a list of 100 items and I need to make it into 10 lists.

I use the follow script, somebody has a better way or more performatic?

```
var subLists = myList.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Item = x })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Index / "MAXIMUM ITEMS ON SUBLIST")
                     .Select(x => x.Select(v => X.Item).ToList());
```

Comment: @Rodrigo: I formatted your code to make it readable.  Take a look at your question and explore what the `{}` button on the editor does.

Comment: Linq is fastest method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a List into smaller lists of N size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463734/split-a-list-into-smaller-lists-of-n-size)

Comment: @Flydog57, thank you for your help!!! I'm new here as a contributor.

Comment: @jdweng, thank you for colaboration!

Answer (score 4):

It`s a slow operation

```
(x, i) => new { Index = i, Item = x }
```

Here's an extension method that will work with any list

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> splitList<T>(List<T> items, int size)  
{        
    for (int i=0; i < items.Count; i+= size) 
    { 
        yield return items.GetRange(i, Math.Min(size, items.Count - i)); 
    }  
}
```

OR better performance

```
public static List<List<T>> splitList<T>(this List<T> items, int size)
{
    List<List<T>> list = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i += size)
        list.Add(items.GetRange(i, Math.Min(size, items.Count - i)));
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a generic answer. One that works for any sequence of any length, where you want to split the sequence into a sequence of sub-sequences, where every sub-sequence has a specified length, except maybe for the last:

For example:

```
IEnumerable<int> items = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17};

// split into subsequences of length 3:
IEnumerable<IEnumerable> splitSequence = items.Split(3);
// splitSequence is a sequence of 3 subsequences:
// {10, 11, 12},
// {13, 14, 15},
// {16, 17}
```

We'll do this by creating an extension method. This way, the method Split can be used as any LINQ function. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx#targetText=Extension%20methods%20are%20a%20very,was%20a%20first%2Dclass%20method.). To make it efficient, I'll enumerate only once, and I don't enumerate any more items than requested for.

```
IEnumerable<TSource> Split(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int splitSize)
{
    // TODO: exception if null source, or non-positive splitSize

    // Get the enumerator and enumerate enough elements to return
    IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        // there are still items in the source; fill a new sub-sequence
        var subSequence = new List<Tsource>(SplitSize);
        do
        {   // add the current item to the list:
            subSequence.Add(enumerator.Current);
        }
        // repeat this until the subSequence is full or until source has no more elements:
        while (subSequence.Count() < splitSize && enumerator.MoveNext());

        // return the subSequence
        yield return subSequence;
     }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Get all Students that live in New York, split them into groups of 10 Students
// and return groups that have at least one Law Student 
var newYorkLasStudentGroups = GetStudents();
   .OrderBy(student => student.UniversityLocation == "New York")
   .Split(10)
   .Where(studentGroup => studentGroup.Any(student => student.Study == "Law"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is not a duplicate. As mentioned, I question a possible form using linq that would be more perfomatic. "For" ties with "range", for example, I am aware of.

Thank you all for your collaboration, comments and possible solutions !!!