# Create IEnumerable collections dynamiclly

Tags: c#, list, ienumerable

I have this problem where I got a list of 5000 and 2000 entries..
The thing is everyone I want to use the 5000 entries list I have to manually type:

```
IEnumerable<string> partList1;
IEnumerable<string> partList2;
IEnumerable<string> partList3;
IEnumerable<string> partList4;
```

And then I go with:

```
partList1 = SplitList(IDList, 0, 999); //args = list,skipvalue,takevalue
```

And I have to do this for all 4 lists and if I use the 2000 entries list I only need two partLists.
How can I go for it to make it dynamiclly that how often 999 fits into the list it creates the partLists itself?

I tried something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < IDList.Count() / 999; i++) {
//and here I stuck
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand the question here. Could you please elaborate bit clear.

Comment: @Thangadurai I am trying to create a IEnumerable<string> dynamiclly for the amount of how much 999 fits into a given number like when the number is 2000 I can create 2 IEnumerable<string> and if the number is like 5000 I am able to create 5 IEnumerable<string> // I don't really know if this makes sense :/ or if am too dumb to get this done

Comment: @darby, One easy way to achieve it would be to make the ```partlist``` itself a list i.e ```IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> partlist``` and fill it as required.

Comment: So you want to split one list into several smaller once of specific size?

Comment: @darby can you please edit your question and clarify further your question ? It's not clear enough.

Comment: I don't really understand

Comment: @gvmani This would be an perfect solution.. Holy heck thank you :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11463734/split-a-list-into-smaller-lists-of-n-size, many of the answer there return inemerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you're trying to split some list items into chunks of 1000 (or 999; that's not clear) items and create an `IEnumerable<string>` for each chunk. If so, you may create a `List<IEnumerable<string>>` to dynamically create your lists and use the [`.Skip()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip) and [`.Take()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take) link methods to "split" the main list.

Try something like this:

```
var listOfLists = new List<IEnumerable<string>>();
const int chunkSize = 1000;

int consumed = 0;
while (consumed < IDList.Count)
{
    listOfLists.Add(IDList.Skip(consumed).Take(chunkSize).ToList());
    consumed += chunkSize;
}
```

Comment: There will be multiple enumerations of the IDlist in the "while" loop, better to convert it to array before the loop, `var idList = IDList as string[] ?? IDList.ToArray();` instead of converting each chunk with `.ToList()`